# Getting Selected Integer from DB Rounding Last Two Digits

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sqlite, better-sqlite3

When I attempt to SELECT data from my sqlite3 database and get the value with the node.js module better-sqlite3, I run into issues where the last two digits of the integer I am getting are rounded.

For example, when I get the value 
`123412341234123412`
it is returned as 
`123412341234123400`

I have used the exact same SQL I am using to select the value in DB Browser and it works as I'd expect (without rounding the number), however when I do this in better-sqlite3 it always rounds these.

Here's the code I'm using in better-sqlite:

```
let getClocked = db.prepare("SELECT messageID FROM clocked WHERE clockedUID = ?").get(id)
console.log(getClocked)
```

The returned value in the console:

```
{ messageID: 643562287101116400 }
```

The value in my database (the same value that was inserted, viewed with DB Browser for SQLite):

```
 643562287101116427
```

I have also tried using .all(), .iterate(), .pluck() and .raw() instead of/alongside .get() which gave me the same result. Happens with other values in the table as well.

(Here is the SQL I used to create the table):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "clocked" (
    "clockedUID" INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "time" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "messageID" INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY("clockedUID")
);
```

New to SQLite and better-sqlite3, so any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Does node support integers or just floating point numbers?

Comment: If not, I think that number is too large for a double to represent exactly as an integer  Also, no need for `UNIQUE` on a primary key column; that's implied by the PK.

Comment: So do you think just storing it as a strong would work just as well?

Comment: Looks like you're right. It's over the MAX_SAFE_INTEGER for node.js. I'll store as string.